How to fill cavity btwn ceiling beams
We ripped out the homasote and old insulation from the ceiling of a 1,200 sq loft (25’x45’) and are now stripping the nice chunky 3”x16” wooden beams running length-wise for a rustic natural look
BUT we wanna have clean solid cavities between the beams
We are debating the material layers, optimizing for (in-order) soundproofing, moisture/heat insulation, cost and aesthetics.
Currently thinking (top>bottom):

cement board
homesite
rock wool
1”x2” wood faring strips
double layer glued sheet rock

Here’s a photo of the goal I saw in a bar one day

Any ideas or recommendations?
Open to completely changing the plan in favor of something surprisingly effective, cheaper or creative.
[Edit 1] Here’s my current situation:

[Edit 2] I am in New York region near a river, so it’s cold and humid half the year.
Thanks!

Got pics of your actual situation?

What sort of climate are you in? That will determine how much insulation you need.
